# I need a javascript round counter and score counter for my game

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to teach myself coding using codeacademy.com. I decided to try and apply some of what I've learnt to build a web based rock, paper, scissors, lizard, spock game. The code for the game works well, I know there's probably better ways to do it but I figure that out later, but I want to add score for the player and the computer plus a round counter. Can anyone tell me how to get the counters working, I've tried a couple things but can't figure it out.

Once I've got the javascript working I'm going to build a single page site to practice HTML and CSS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
    var rock = "rock"
    var paper = "paper"
    var scissors = "scissors"
    var lizard = "lizard"
    var spock = "spock"
    var compScore = 1
    var playerScore = 1

    function roundUp() {
      round += 1
    }

    function compare(choice1, choice2) {
      var round = 1
      var computerChoice = Math.random()
      if (computerChoice <= 0.2) {
        choice2 = "rock";
      } else if(computerChoice <= 0.4) {
        choice2 = "paper";
      } else if (computerChoice <= 0.6) {
        choice2 = "scissors";
      } else if (computerChoice <= 0.8) {
        choice2 = "lizard";
      }
      else {
        choice2 = "spock";
      }

      if (choice1 === choice2) {
        document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML  = "Round tied!"; 
      } else if (choice1 === rock) {
        if (choice2 === paper) { 
          compScore += 1
          document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML  = 
            "Paper covers rock, computer wins"; 
        }
        else if (choice2 === scissors) { 
          playerScore += 1
          document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML  = 
            "Rock breaks scissors, you win"; 
        }
        else if (choice2 === lizard) { 
          playerScore += 1
          document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML  = 
            "Rock crushes lizzard, you win"; 
        }
        else {
          compScore += 1 
          document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML  = 
            "Spock vaporises rock, computer wins"; 
        }
      } else if (choice1 === paper) {
        if (choice2 === rock) {
          document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML  = 
            "Paper covers rock, you win"; 
          playerScore += 1
        } else if (choice2 === scissors) {
          document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML  = 
            "Scissors cut paper, computer wins"; 
          compScore += 1 
        } else if (choice2 === lizard) {
          document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML  = 
            "lizard eats paper, computer wins"; 
          compScore += 1 
        } else {
          document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML  = 
            "Paper disproves spock, you win"; 
          playerScore += 1
        }
      } else if (choice1 === scissors) {
        if (choice2 === rock) {
          document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML  = 
            "Rock breaks scissors, computer wins"; 
          compScore += 1 
        } else if (choice2 === paper) {
          document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML  = 
            "Scissors cut paper, you win"; 
          playerScore += 1
        }else if (choice2 === lizard) {
          document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML  = 
            "Scissors decapitate lizard, you win"; 
          playerScore += 1
        } else {
          document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML  = 
            "Spock smashes scissors, computer wins"; 
          compScore += 1 
        }
      } else if (choice1 === lizard) {
        if (choice2 === rock) {
          document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML  = 
            "Rock crushes lizzard, computer wins"; 
          compScore += 1 
        } else if (choice2 === scissors) {
          document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML  = 
            "Scissors decapitate lizard, computer wins"; 
          compScore += 1 
        } else if (choice2 === paper) {
          document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML  = 
            "Lizard eats paper, you win"; 
          playerScore += 1
        } else {
          document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML  = 
            "Lizard poisons spock, you win"; 
          playerScore += 1
        }
      } else {
        if (choice2 === rock) {
          document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML  = 
            "Spock vaporises rock, you win"; 
          playerScore += 1
        } else if (choice2 === scissors) {
          document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML  = 
            "Spock smashes scissors, you win"; 
          playerScore += 1
        } else if (choice2 === paper) {
          document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML  = 
            "Paper disproves spock, computer wins"; 
          compScore += 1 
        } else {
          document.getElementById("winner").innerHTML  = 
            "Lizard poisons spock, computer wins"; 
          compScore += 1 
        }
      }

      document.getElementById("choice1").innerHTML  = choice1
      document.getElementById("choice2").innerHTML  = choice2
      document.getElementById("computerChoice").innerHTML  = computerChoice
      document.getElementById("playerScore").innerHTML  = playerScore
      document.getElementById("compScore").innerHTML  = compScore
      document.getElementById("round").innerHTML  = round

      roundUp()
    }

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>

    <h1>My Web Page</h1>

    <h3>Round</h3>
    <p id="round"></p>

    <h4>Player Choice</h4>
    <p id="choice1"></p>
    <h4>Player Score</h4>
    <p id="playerScore"></p>

    <h4>Computer Choice</h4>
    <p id="choice2"></p>
    <h4>Computer Score</h4>
    <p id="compScore"></p>

    <h4>And the winner is</h4>
    <p id="winner"></p>        

    <button type="button" onclick="compare(rock, choice2)">Rock</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="compare(paper, choice2)">Paper</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="compare(scissors, choice2)">scissors</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="compare(lizard, choice2)">lizard</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="compare(spock, choice2)">Spock</button>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: At least you're missing a semicolon.

Comment: This would be a lot less code if you used [jQuery](http://jquery.com/). Using `document.getElementById()` is pretty hack. At the very least write your own wrapper function for getting those to cut down on the verbosity. You're also in dire need of a `switch` statement instead of a whole heap of `if`s.

Comment: Hi tadman, thanks for your feedback. I'm really new to javascript, I only started the codeacademy.com java module last saturday and only got to learn about switches after I'd created most of the game. I should get to the jquery module in about 4 or 5 days so I will probably have a go at rewriting it once I've learnt a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create `round` as global variable as you did it with `rock`, `paper`, `scissors` etc. Define round the same way

```
var round = 0;
```

and your `roundUp` function should work as expected.

**EDIT**: You also forgot to end your statements with semicolons. And I think you don't need to send `choice2` as parameter on button click while you're setting it inside your function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to take `var round = 1` out of compare() because every time you run the compare function, round is going to reset back to 1. Instead put var round = 0 at the top with your other variable declarations.  Also, I'd stick the script at the bottom to ensure the page elements load before your script. I'd strongly suggest using semicolons after your variable declarations. http://jsfiddle.net/ja4m0qoL/

Comment: This worked a treat, I have transferred the bits of code you added in the link to make sure I fully understood where I went wrong. Thank you for taking the time to answer my question and create the code in jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 1):

You need to run a function which will update the playerScore, like you did for the round counter when a player makes a choice. I would pass in a param which tells roundUp() which player scored:

```
roundUp(winner){
    round++; //increments round
    if(winner === computer){
        compScore++; //increments score
        document.getElementById("compScore").innerHTML  = compScore; //updates HTML
    }
    else if(winner === player){
        playerScore++; //increments score
        document.getElementById("playerScore").innerHTML  = playerScore; //updates HTML
    }
};
```